# Node.js running Python scripts with librairies

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mongodb, docker

1. I have a Node.js app that makes GET calls every minute to an API.
2. The data it receives gets stored into a MongoDB database.
3. Simultaneously, the Node.js runs a Python script (with the Keras library) on that data every minute.
4. Based on the output of the Python script, the Node.js app makes a POST call to the same API.
5. This would all run on Docker 24/7 after I download Node.js, npm, python's keras library and mongo.

How should the Node.js app and the Python script interact? Can I have a simple node-cmd npm package to run the script from the Node.js code or is it more complex? Am I missing anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `child_process` from `Node.js` documentation ([Link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var output = '';
var child = exec('python some/file.py');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    output += data;
});
child.on('close', function() {
    // Make your API call here
    console.log(result);
});
```